# How to make python loop "not waiting" for finish previous command?

Tags: python

I need to open VLC and play video, depending on the variable "start".
In this example, loop continues after ad1.mp4 finished.
Is there a way, how to make loop not waiting? So ad1.mp4 start playing and loop will continue.

```py
start = 1

while True:
    if start == 1:
        os.system("vlc --video ad/ad1.pm4")
    if start == 2:
        os.system("vlc --video ad/ad2.pm4")
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Look up the `break` keyword. If a condition is met, so your think then cal break to break out of the loop.

Comment: see continue statement : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_continue_statement.htm 
Also check Python multi threading : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to not wait for function to finish python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649263/how-to-not-wait-for-function-to-finish-python)

Comment: You cannot do that with [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). For advanced subprocess management (including asynchronous execution), see the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Or if you want to use [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), then see [Subprocesses in `asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subprocess library.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["vlc","--video ","ad/ad1.pm4"])
```

This allows to spawn a new process and not making python to wait until it finishes.

Library link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html